# TomEE + OpenJPA using ManyToMany does not work

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am throwing in the towel. I do not understand, how difficult can it be?

I have two Entities `User` and `Group`, having a many to many relationship. `Group` manages the relationship. So in `Group` I have:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "GROUPS", catalog = "", schema = "GROUPADMIN")
public class Group {
  ...
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
    name = "GROUP_USERS",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")}
  )
  private Set<User> users;
```

Then for `User` I create the entity something as follows:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "USERS", catalog = "", schema = "GROUPADMIN")
public class User {
  ...
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="users")
  private Set<Group> groups;
```

Then in my backing bean, actually a `@Named("registry")`, I store a reference to a retrieved `user` as a property with the same name.

Then I use that backing bean royally in my JSF

```html
Hello <h:outputLabel value="#{registry.user.firstName}"/>
<h:panelGroup>
  <h:dataTable value="#{registry.user.groups}" var="g">
    <f:facet name="header">Properties List</f:facet>
    <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">Group</f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{g.id}"/>
    </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

For those interested in the tables:

```sql
create table "GROUPADMIN".GROUPS
(
  ID VARCHAR(15) not null primary key
);
create table "GROUPADMIN".USERS
(
  ID VARCHAR(50) not null primary key,
  PASSWORD VARCHAR(50),
  FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(50),
  LAST_NAME VARCHAR(50)
);
create table "GROUPADMIN".GROUP_USERS
(
  GROUP_ID VARCHAR(15) not null,
  USER_ID VARCHAR(50) not null,
  primary key (GROUP_ID, USER_ID)
);
```

First thing noticed is that groups appears to be empty, not null, but empty (verified with debugging etc). So I understood that by default a `@ManyToMany` would use Lazy binding, so I changed this to `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` (not that this should even matter). After doing so, things really got bizarre ...

At this point EL started complaining that the id property didn't exist on `"#{g.id}"`:

```
Caused by:
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException - Property 'id' not found on type org.apache.openjpa.util.java$util$HashSet$proxy
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:266)
```

Why is it trying to retrieve property `id` on a `HashSet` proxy, and not on a `Group`?

So me being curious what I actually got into that `g` attribute I got from the `<h:dataTable>`, I tried to output it simply using `<h:outputText value="#{g}"/>` ... result was really interesting ...

What `g` printed out was not just one element out of the `Set<Group>`, but was actually the collection itself, which matches the earlier shown exception ... that's more indicative for a bug in the API or integration?

So basically it looks like several things are broken, although I suspect it all relates to one an the same issue.

Note that I used a basic off-the-shelf TomEE, latest version, no customization (no enhancer for JPA also).

Comment: Can you please post the group, user and GROUP_USERS tables.

Comment: Try if it helps to add the schema to the @JoinTable annotation. If that doesn't help check the log of tomee to see if openjpa reports any problems.

Comment: Ok, I found a way to fix it, just not a way to explain. Once I replace `Set<xxx>` with `List<xxx>` everything starts to work as expected. That was just based on a hunch. However, I do explicitly remember reading that I should be able to use `Set<xxx>` as an indication that I would not expect any duplicates. To confirm, I read up on [JSR 338: JavaTM Persistence 2.1](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338).

Comment: I submitted it as a bug: [Jira Issue OpenJPA-2546](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2546)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why it should work: [JSR 338: JavaTM Persistence 2.1.](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338)

Bug submitted: [Jira Issue OpenJPA-2546](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2546) (please vote on getting this resolved).

Workaround: replace `Set<T>` with `List<T>` as a workaround.